# javascript delete file on unlimited upload button

Tags: javascript, removechild, createtextnode

thanks for the upcoming assistance, I am working on a uploader and trying to add a javascript delete link to each extra input field. I have one that adds a child.

[image]

here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPPmYP

What I am wanting to do is during creation of the extra input fields, Here is my code if anyone is able to help.

I also tried these methods and they didnt work

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function _add_more() {

    files.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    var del = document.createTextNode("Delete ");
    document.getElementById("files").appendChild(del);

    var extra = document.createElement('input');
    extra.type="file";
    extra.id="images[]";
    extra.name="images[]";
    extra.size="50";
    extra.accept="image/jpeg";
    document.getElementById("files").appendChild(extra);
}
</script>
```

I tried changing what I have for that line into

```
var del = document.createTextNode('<a href="javascript:_del_extra();">delete</a> ');
```

But it just showed it as text instead of making it a clickable link, I am really unsure on how to create the function to remove a child without effecting any others. Thank you for the upcoming support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to attach an event handler to the click of the delete link.

Something like this. (*Updated as per comment*)

```
<script language="javascript">
function _add_more() {

    var del = document.createElement("a");
    del.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete"));
    del.href="#"; // Apply link styling

    var extra = document.createElement('input');
    extra.type="file";
    extra.id="images[]";
    extra.name="images[]";
    extra.size="50";
    extra.accept="image/jpeg";

    var additionalFile = document.createElement('span');
    additionalFile.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    additionalFile.appendChild(del);
    additionalFile.appendChild(extra);

    document.getElementById("files").appendChild(additionalFile);

    del.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        additionalFile.parentElement.removeChild(additionalFile);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but the issue seems to be that it doesnt make it a clickable link, it turns it into a text link pretty much showing the code. Here is my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPPmYP

Comment: That is because you are using createTextNode. I will update my example to append an <a> element.

Comment: Thanks so much, one more thing, how do I do it so if they have a extra textbox, then its required? I would use **extra.required = "required";** right?

Comment: Yes, you could use HTML5 validation to enforce a required field. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required

Comment: Thanks for the time to help me out! Solved. @Sam